# How to disable alert notifications in iOS when battery drops to 20% and then to 10%?

Tags: ios, battery, notifications

Is there a way to disable these alerts that appear when battery drops down to 20% and later on to 10%? *(iPhone 4s iOS 8.4.1)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no ways to disable those alerts unless your device is jailbroken. In that case (device is jailbroken), you can search Cydia for a tweak that disables those alerts.